# how to get the delivery report URL value when replying to a SMS using kannel?

Tags: php, sms, report, kannel

i am sending a SMS, that goes through just fine. I also see it in the `dlr` table as sent.

the problem i have is when reply to the SMS. One of the parameters [here](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.4/userguide-1.4.4/userguide.html) `%R` suppose to carry over the `the delivery report URL value`, witch i am sending,  but it comes in empty.

What i am trying to do is to track with message i am replying to, so im trying to get any information that will allow me to connect the reply to the initial SMS, like the message sent, or the message sent id or `delivery report URL`

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post more information? An example of your send-sms URL, the DLR URL maybe?

Comment: @pilsetnieks i don't use a DLR URL. and i send sms by directly inserting in the send_sms table. i pass the from, to, provider and service. Service values get transferred to the dlr table